# React Native - Use a keyExtractor with FlatList

Tags: arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have been getting the:

```
"VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key property on an item or provide a custom keyExtractor"
```

pretty confusing..., the array i am passing it has a key property defined in each object in the array. I have that array defined in this.state. I ran a quick print out in the console to be sure:
[print out of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkzI4.png)

Each object in array is defined as:

```
  var obj = {key: doc.id, value: doc.data()};
```

(doc and data being from another part of my app, but I know doc.id is unique)

After some googling I then tried to define a Key Extractor like so:

```
_keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.key;
```

and then here is my flatlist definition:

```
  <FlatList
        style={{}}
        data={this.state.FeedDataCollection}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={(rowData) =>this.RenderFeedCard(rowData)}
      />
```

Still receiving the same error, at this point not really sure how to handle this or what it is doing wrong. Any Ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: try `_keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.item.key;`

Comment: wish that was the issue, when I do that I get the error "Cannot read property 'key' of undefined"

Comment: try _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index. does it fix the warning? if yes, then the problem is with the item keys

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> "VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key
> property on an item or provide a custom keyExtractor"

This is a warning that the elements of the list are missing keys. These unique keys are what allow the VirtualizedList (which is what FlatList is built on) to track items and are really important in terms of efficiency.

You will have to choose a unique key prop, like an `id` or an `email`.

The `keyExtractor` falls back to using the `index` by default. But the warning will remain visible.

**Example:**
an object defined as `{key: doc.id, value: doc.data()}` can be used in the extractor as:

```js
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
```

Flatlist component should look like that:

```js
<FlatList
  style={{}}
  data={this.state.FeedDataCollection}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
  renderItem={(rowData) =>this.RenderFeedCard(rowData)}
/>
```

Comment: beginning to think there is some sort of a bug in play here.. tried both of those options, no luck :(

Comment: wish there was more info i could provide but not sure what else to say.. I know key is unique, but i tried index as well.. no luck

Comment: Good to hear! The way with the keyextractor is pretty standard.

Comment: return index in keyExtractor is totally wrong. If your items do not have anything unique it is better to add that property

Comment: @Akis, I can't change my vote, can you please edit your answer, If no key is provided react will use an index anyway. But it is useless

Comment: @YernarAmergaliyev index is used by default indeed, not sure if it happens on all versions or just the latest ones

Answer (score 39):

i do this and work for me:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key'+index}
```

Comment: Yes. You need to return a `string` so `keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}` in case the field `item.id` is either `integer` or other `datatypes` different from string

Comment: Incredible incorrect answer. In react, keys can help with some type of caching, but when you use index instead real representation of object (like `id`), it will break this totally

Comment: as i know keyextractor get a  ' uniq string provider'
if you have this uniq string in your datas-ource you can use  that like other sayes: item.key , ind when you dont have that uniq string you must to create them!
in this way yo will get: "key0" , "key1" ...

Comment: This keyExtractor will only work, if the order of your list items doesn't change

Answer (score 4):

The importance of this error is at the point where you start to change or delete any of the objects of your array because of how your list will get updated if you don't provide that key.

The way React Native deals with a change to your list without a key is to delete everything visible on the screen and then looks at the new array of data and renders a single element for each one.

We don't want React Native to rebuild an entire list just because of one small change to the array of data. Ideally, we want React Native to detect specifically the object we deleted or changed and update accordingly, but that will not happen if we do not provide the key.

The key property allows React Native to track these list of objects and that way it can keep track of what you are modifying or deleting and just delete that particular element with a particular key.

This way the list does not need to be rebuilt from scratch. The key will allow React Native to tie the definition of an object of data with some element that appears on the screen.

It's just allowing React Native to track the different list of objects we are rendering to the screen. It's also a performance optimization on making updates to our list.

Answer (score 2):

@Sarantis Tofas has the correct answer. Solved it for me!
Two additional notes based on the comments:

1. If you use index then make sure to use index.toString() or you'll get a different warning (*Failed child context type - type number supplied to CellRenderer expected string*).
2. FlatList will work with index by default if you don't have key properties or a keyExtractor defined, but it will still throw a warning.

Answer (score 2):

```
keyExtractor ={(item, index) => `${item.key}${index}`}
```

this worked for me. Don't need to concatenate strings
also this will work if you dont have any unique key.

```
keyExtractor = {(item, index) => `${index}`}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Best unique key extractor for react native**

function looks like:

```
  keyExtractor = item => {
    return item.id.toString() + new Date().getTime().toString() + (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(new Date().getTime()))).toString();  };
```

or without item fields:

```
  keyExtractor = () => {
    return new Date().getTime().toString() + (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(new Date().getTime()))).toString();  };
```

Comment: If you need generate unique id using timestamp values, your data structure needs to be adjusted to have an unique id per item.

Comment: This won't work if data is updated, as the key is not a pure function of the item (i.e., it won't return the same value for the same item when invoked again)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in my case, FlatList **data** prop value was not an array type (it was empty object) so when I add `keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}` it made an error.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

this will work sure. First generate random number.

```
let generateRandomNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
```

then call where you need generate random number. like :-

```
{ id: generateRandomNum().toString(), value: 'your value'}
```

//below i share small part of my code for better understand

```
const addGoalHandler = enteredInputGoal => {
console.log('random nub', generateRandomNum());
setCourseGoals(courrentGoals => [...courrentGoals, { id: generateRandomNum().toString(), value: enteredInputGoal }]);
  };
```

and finally use in FlatList

```
<FlatList keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id} data={courseGoals} renderItem={itemData =>itemData.item.value } />
```

Answer (score 1):

keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key'+index} worked for me.

Comment: Yes, but item is then unused and marked yellow in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `listkey` instead of `keyExtractor`, it worked for me