# ReactNative Expo App Very Slow Performance

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native currently developing an app 
All the app should contain

1- Carousel

2- 12 Category Card

3- 1 Category Page Contain Cards with Images and some texts (The card data will be fetched from an API)

I'm Using Expo App But the Performance is extremely slow in iPhone 6 For Example
it's fine in iPhone 7 and above

Scrolling Performance is bad
Navigation Performance is bad

Project EXPO QR LINK: `https://expo.io/@ov3rcontrol/Weddi`
Github Project Link : `https://github.com/Ov3rControl/Weddi`
(Feel Free To Pull Request and Contribute to improving its a performance )
How can I improve my React-Native App Performance? what am i doing wrong here that is causing this performance issues

**EDIT 1: i Get Warrnings 1- Overwriting fontFamily style attribute preprocessor

```
                    2- Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop   

                    3- VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow
```

to update - make sure your render item function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate**

EDIT 2 : React Dev Tools [image]

Comment: I see you lack the KeyExtractor of the FlatList. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953662/react-native-use-a-keyextractor-with-flatlist

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it and the warning is removed but in terms of performance app still slow any other ideas? :)

Comment: I can’t run your app on Expo. Anw, try to remove images and test the performance. It might affect the render process. But remember, the app performance which runs on Expo is always worse than the standalone app. iPhone 6 only has 1 GB of RAM and a 32bit processor, so test the app on Expo is not a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow`
Use pagination to resolve this. Limit the data array size to solve that. Flatlist renders the element on by one and if there are lot of elements then the performance would be slow. Also try using some optimisation procedures of flatlist like :

`removeClippedSubviews`
`initialNumToRender`
`maxToRenderPerBatch`
`windowSize` and layout height and width pre calculation if those are static : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout

https://medium.com/sanjagh/how-to-optimize-your-react-native-flatlist-946490c8c49b

Comment: I was considering to replace the flat list with https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview because they say it's built for performance what do you think?

Comment: You definitely can. But make sure to go through the open issues. As flatlist comes in box with react native but the github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview is a 3rd party library which might have issues. If this meets your expecations then you are good to go.

Comment: Also note that the library has documented : 
 `compute height upfront so that RecyclerListView can compute layout in one pass rather than waiting for the draw to happen`.
which I already said in my comment above that you might have to calculate the heigth and width and provide that to flatlist for fast rendering which they are doing.

Comment: how can i compute the height of the card upfront is there is a tutorial for it?
also if i do it is it going to be responsive in all mobile screens ?
thanks

Comment: that means giving static height and width. Don't use onLayout function as it gets called everytime and if you use that inside a renderer list like flatlist it will get called everysingle time whenever a single list gets rendered. This will cause massive memory issue. 
`Adding getItemLayout can be a great performance boost for lists of several hundred items. Remember to include separator length (height or width) in your offset calculation if you specify ItemSeparatorComponent.`

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout

Comment: After upgrading expo SDK 48 to 49 sectionlist and react navigation slowdown the app