# issue with rendering the React-native flatList

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Good afternoon StackOverflowers I'm working on building a RssFeeder app in order to work on my React Native skills but somehow ran into a problem which I wanted to fix now, as I try to render my objects which I get from an outside API called newsAPI and I try to show them into a flatList which for some reason doesn't work as I hope; here is my HomeScreen part for the flatList:

```
 return (
    <View>
      <Text>We have found {articles?.length} articles</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={articles}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        horizontal
        scrollEnabled
        keyExtractor={(articles) => articles?.name}
        extraData={articles} 
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Detail")}>
              <DetailScreen result={item} />
            </TouchableOpacity>

         
          );
        }}
      ></FlatList>
```

I'm pretty sure that API works properly cause the first line which shows the length of the articles shows the exact number, in addition, I added a Text component after  `<DetailScreen result={item} />` and it shows me Text components 10 times, so I wonder what is the problem with the code.

**result** in the  `<DetailScreen result={item} />` is a madeup prop for my second screen called 'DetailScreen' to carry all the data from Home to DetailScreen.

Also, this is what DetailScreen looks like at the moment.

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen";

const DetailScreen = (result) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{result.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default DetailScreen;
```

**This is a sample from the API:**

*{
"source": {
"id": "techcrunch",
"name": "TechCrunch"
},
"author": "Jonathan Shieber",
"title": "How did Atlanta become a top breeding ground for billion-dollar startups in the Southeast?",
"description": "Over the past five years, the Southeastern region, led by Atlanta, has gone from being “one of the best kept secrets” in tech, to a vibrant ecosystem teeming with a herd of the billion dollar tech businesses that are referred to in the investment world as “un…",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/2021/05/02/how-did-atlanta-become-a-top-breeding-ground-for-billion-dollar-startups-in-the-southeast/",
"urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/GettyImages-467404053.jpg?w=600",
"publishedAt": "2021-05-02T15:25:38Z",
"content": "Over the past five years, the Southeastern region, led by Atlanta, has gone from being “one of the best kept secrets” in tech, to a vibrant ecosystem teeming with a herd of the billion dollar tech bu… [+18425 chars]"
},*

Comment: I'm not familiar with RN, but I think there you need to iterate over the articles. So instead of <<keyExtractor={(articles) => articles?.name}>> try with <<keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}>> May I've missing something, but I think you'll get an idea. I've got that example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953662/react-native-use-a-keyextractor-with-flatlist)

Comment: @boolfalse Thanks for the response, I don't have any problem with extracting the key, the keyExtractor components will change base on the API you are working, within this sample API because all of the components of it had the same "id" I couldn't find a better key instead of title((name is wrong here I will change it)) I believe the problem should be in the renderItem property but I can't be so sure about it as you know.

Comment: @navidabasi could you post what one item in the `articles` look like, and what `DetailSscreen` is expecting as props?

Comment: @nipuna777 I already added a sample from API and DetailScreen suppose to show me the description and Image of chosen topic from API so it will take the 'result' from Detail screen

Comment: Have you tried changing `(result) => {` to `({result}) => {`? Right now `result` refers to `props` in the `DetailScreen`

Comment: @navidabasi I hope you destructured the HomeScreen like so `const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => { ... return () };` given that you are using navigation. instead of props.navigation.?

Comment: @navidabasi I don't understand the issue. If you are able to render the title 10 time then the FlatList is rendering correctly I think. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Subha  This is the const home screen details | 


const HomeScreen = (navigation) => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

Comment: @Subha thats my problem too! if its working properly which seems to be the case here why it wont render any thing into the expo app on my phone? till now I'm sure that API works correctly as I'm testing it with {articles.length} and shows 10 result which is correct and flatList also shows the Text component while I'm testing it so it must be something wrong with rendingItem or flatlist props!

Comment: @nipuna777 that was the plan to pass the information from deconstructed data (item) to the result which is a prop for the detailscreen

Comment: @navidabasi But in the  example you've pasted, you are trying to getting `props` when you really need `props.results`. Did you try changing it to `({result})` as suggested earlier?

Comment: @nipuna777 I'm following a move from udemy course the man in the tutorial said we are going to pass a custom prop called result into the detailscreen and he started to code it something like this so after watching it I tried to pave it into my use case
Also ({result}) this won't work as I told you result itself is a custom prop to take data and we are not passing it right now in here as I learned react-native the code you wrote is for when you want to pass a prop into a variable am I right?

Comment: @navidabasi I agree with @nipuna777 if you correct 2 typos like so `keyExtractor={(articles) => articles.name}` & `const DetailScreen = (result) =>` the code should work. Please try this first and let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution which is depend on the version of react-navigation that you are using the way that you can pass the parameters to others screens will change eventually because I'm using react navigation V5 and by considering this link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params I should pass the params in this way in comparison with the

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Detail")}>
              <DetailScreen result={item} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

To be honest that's a bit weird, why we need to change way we code depend on the version of react navigation :p

```
   <View>
     <Text>We have found {articles?.length} articles</Text>
     <FlatList
       data={articles}
       showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
       // horizontal
       scrollEnabled
       keyExtractor={(articles) => articles?.title}
       extraData={articles} //makes flatList to re-render each time articles changes.
       renderItem={({ item }) => {
         //renderItem takes 'objects' from 'data' (data and item are keyWords for flatLists)
         return (
           <TouchableOpacity
             style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
             onPress={() =>
               navigation.navigate("Detail", {
                 article: item, //in navigation V5 we use this method to pass the chosen params(item) by setting a chosen name to mentioned screen("Detail") then we use useRoute to capture those.
               })
             }
           >
             {/* <DetailScreen result={item} /> */}
             <Text>{item.title}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>

           //<Text>{item?.title}</Text>
         );
       }}
     ></FlatList>
```

If you didn't understand the code properly try to focus on the comments that I put in the code.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others and me in the comments
There are 2 syntax issues

1. Change `articles?.name` to `articles.name` in the keyExtractor
2. Destructure the props correctly in DetailScreen from `(result)` to `({result})`
   Both these are important for your code to work correctly.

Lastly, I noticed your `articles` data is an object {} while data in FlatList must be an array []. So please transform the article data you are receiving from the API into an array and it will work. [Link to React Native official docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-data) where you will see FlatList only accepts array in the data prop.

Here is the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-raman-kludi?file=/src/App.js) where you will see I transformed your articles object data into updatedArticles array and passed the updatedArticles into the FlatList and it is rending it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort to my problem, found the solution from one of my friends he mentioned that because I'm using V5 of react-navigation I should follow this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params instead of the solution which I learned from the tutorial( it was navigation v3 in video)  altought by considering your comment I should say that articles?.name is a true statement it is like to write an if statement like if articles gives you an answer then find articles.name in addition API gives me an array of objects and that wasn't the problem either Thanks Subha for all the effort.